# Is there a way to style Angular Material Tabs locally?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material-tab

I am trying to style a mat-tab locally,

I understand that :ng-deep affects the style to be global,

But is there a way to change style per component?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by locally, just provide the expected result... will give you styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to apply styles to only one mat-table component. i handled this by wrapping the styles which i want to apply inside the selector of the component. so inside your root styles.scss you can do something like this.

```
// styles.scss
parent-component-selector {
  mat-table {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

this will apply the styles only when the mat-table is inside the parent-component selector.